# Hadoop - Can I set task memory limit lower than 2GB

Tags: memory, hadoop

As title.
Does anyone know how to limit the hadoop's memory.
I want to let hadoop machine to slove the task with lower memory.
Because I want to know if a hadoop machine have insufficient memory, what happen will hadoop machine do.

Comment: Do you want to limit the memory of the child JVMs (i.e: map/reduce tasks running on the tasktrackers) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the memory allocated to a NameNode by setting HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS in hadoop-env.sh to include a JVM option for memory size. Eg, for Sun JVM, **-Xmx2000m** would indicate that 2GB of memory would be allocated to the NameNode. Please note that 1G of memory for a NameNode is usually enough for a few million files.